# css style to jquery - more than one property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got in my css file this:

```
    background:url("img/gold1.gif") repeat-x center;
```

and now I want to change it into jQuery language but I 'dont know how :(
I have this:

```
$('#example').css( {"background": "url('img/gold1.gif')", "background-repeat": "repeat-x", "background-position": "center"; });
```

And it doesn't work. Any help, please?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work".

Comment: This `"background-position": "center";` is invalid syntax. Remove the semi colon

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't see that :)

Comment: Did that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! How can I close this question?

Comment: I shall add as an answer. Then you can accept and that will close it

Comment: Flagging to close as caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: @Roberto Closing your question is in all likelihood the right thing to do here. There should be a link to delete it at the bottom of the question, just below the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `"background-position": "center";` is invalid syntax. Remove the semi colon

Answer (score 0):

This should work, remove semicolon after center:

```
$('#example').css({
    "background": "url('img/gold1.gif')",
    "background-repeat": "repeat-x",
    "background-position": "center"
});
```

Comment: What? A downvote for a good answer...Pff all because I did not see the comment...

Comment: Wasn't me if that helps

Comment: @CarlMarkham Thanks :)...I didn't really care, was just surprised how easy some people downvote :)

Comment: I don't downvote too. Thanks for help but Mikey was first so I accept his answer. <5>